# Repeat sound button doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I've just started learning web dev and designed this website for my school's spelling bee contest:

https://rawgit.com/evandocarmo/spellingbee/v0.1/index.html

I also designed a little game in which students listen to words and spell them out. I was helped here to get it running:

https://rawgit.com/evandocarmo/spellingbee/v0.1/game.html

I can't make the goddamn repeat button work, though.

my java script code is this to get a random word from my object and play its audio property:

```
var play = function() {
var list = Object.keys(words);
window.randomWord = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
var playWord = words[window.randomWord].audio
playWord.play()
```

I used window to create a global variable that could be accessed by a second function, which works the repeat button:

```
var repeat = function(){
var playWord = words[window.randomWord].audio
playWord.play()
```

My biggest frustration is that I did this at home last night and it worked both offline and online!

And this morning at work it just stopped working =\ I click the button and it doesn't repeat the word. The rest works just fine.

any tips?

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me. What browser are you using? I can get the "Repeat" button to not work, but only if I don't click "New Word" first, which is what you would expect. If you open developer tools (F12 on IE, right click the page and select developer tools on chrome), and then try clicking the button, does it show an error that might tell you what the problem is?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was using google chrome portable because we are not allowed to install anything but IE at school.

I tried it in IE and it works just fine. Go figure.

No error messages in the console for google chrome portable though.

Comment: It may be a caching issue. Try `Ctrl` + `F5` to load latest files.

Comment: Hi! It still doesn't work. Thanks, though.